# How are different resolution settings for videos handled by server and client based on setting and connection speed?

Tags: design, stream-processing, video

I was watching youtube and squinted at the text in the video and wondered what happens when I switch from `720p` to `1080p`.

- Does the streaming service, Youtube and or any other, just have the files in different resolution  at the time of creation and then ping the client to see how fast the connection is before deciding packets of which resolution to send over?
- Does the streaming service even create different resolutions for the video when uploaded by the poster?
- Or is there something on the client (Youtube page or app for mobile devices) that figures it out what resolution is best to send over?
- How does this handling differ from when the connection speed deteriorates and doesn't match the user's setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different questions here that will be quite out of scope for an answer here to encompass. To get you started, read up on [Adaptive Bitrate Streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming?wprov=sfla1), a family of protocols and techniques for changing bitrates on the fly.

For the rest of your questions, there can be multiple answers. If the majority of your users stream in either 360, 720 or 1080, it makes sense to pre-encode to those bitrates to save on CPU usage while streaming... unless, for your use case, you are more constrained by disk space than CPU (e.g. a site where 99% of video is rarely requested). You might employ any number of strategies and heuristics to decide which bitrates to preconvert, which to encode on the fly, and which to keep, cached, for future viewers. This is not unique to video streaming, and is similar to space/CPU tradeoffs everywhere.